# Polynomial long division in other basis

Tags: polynomials, change-of-basis

## Question

How do I perform a long division between $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ when they are not written in canonical base?

## Description

Let $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ be polynomials of degree $n$ and $m$. I want to find two polynomials $a(x)$ and $r(x)$ such

$$p(x) = q(x) \cdot a(x) + r(x)$$

$a(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $(n-m)$ and $r(x)$'s degree is at maximum $(m-1)$.

In canonical base, we can write these polynomials as

$$\begin{align}p(x)& =p_0+p_1x+\cdots+p_nx^n \\ q(x)& =q_0+q_1x+\cdots+q_mx^m \\ a(x)& =a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_{n-m}x^{n-m} \\ r(x)& =r_0+r_1x+\cdots+r_{m-1}x^{m-1} \\ \end{align}$$

But if these polynomials are written in another basis (like bezier shown bellow), how can I find the coefficients?

$$B_{i,n}(x)=\binom{n}{i}\left(1-x\right)^{n-i}\cdot x^i$$

$$\begin{align}p(x)& =P_0\cdot B_{0,n}(x)+P_1\cdot B_{1,n}(x)+\cdots+P_n\cdot B_{n,n}(x) \\ q(x)&=Q_0\cdot B_{0,m}(x)+Q_1\cdot B_{1,m}(x)+\cdots+Q_m\cdot B_{m}(x) \\ a(x)&=A_0\cdot B_{0,n-m}(x)+A_1\cdot B_{1,n-m}(x)+\cdots+A_{n-m}\cdot B_{n-m,n-m}(x) \\ r(x)&=R_0\cdot B_{0,m-1}(x)+R_1\cdot B_{1,m-1}(x)+\cdots+R_{m-1}\cdot B_{m-1,m-1}(x) \\ \end{align}$$

My main interest is in bezier, but maybe There are other polynomial families like [Laguerre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials) or [Legendre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) which may be useful the property of orthogonality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we consider the $(n+1)$-dimensional vector space of polynomials $F_{n}$ of degree less or equal $n$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$. The polynomials
\begin{align*}
e_k(x):=x^k\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad 0\leq k\leq n
\end{align*}
are a basis of $F_{n}$. The Bezier polynomials
\begin{align*}
B_{k,n}(x):=\binom{n}{k}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}\qquad\qquad 0\leq k\leq n
\end{align*}
are also a basis of $F_n$ since each $B_{k,n}$ has order $k, 0\leq k\leq n$. Here we use the term *[order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_a_polynomial)* as the degree of its non-zero term of lowest degree.

> We are looking for coefficients $a_{k,j}$ in
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{x^k=\sum_{j=0}^n a_{k,j}B_{j,n}(x)\qquad\qquad 0\leq k\leq n}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

In order to find the coefficients we start with a small number, let's say $n=4$ and check if we can see a relationship. It is easy to represent $B_{k,n}(x)$ in terms of the standard basis $(e_k)_{0\leq k\leq n}=(x^k)_{0\leq k\leq n}$. We have in case $n=4$
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&-4&6&-4&1\\
&4&-12&12&-4\\
&&6&-12&6\\
&&&4&-4\\
&&&&1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\x\\x^2\\x^3\\x^4
\end{pmatrix}
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
1-4x+6x^2-4x^3+x^4\\
4x-12x^2+12x^3-4x^4\ \ \\
6x^2-12x^3+6x^4\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \\
4x^3-4x^4\qquad\qquad\qquad\ \ \\
x^4\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
\end{pmatrix}\\
\begin{pmatrix}
1&-4&6&-4&1\\
&4&-12&12&-4\\
&&6&-12&6\\
&&&4&-4\\
&&&&1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\x\\x^2\\x^3\\x^4
\end{pmatrix}
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
B_{0,4}(x)\\
B_{1,4}(x)\\
B_{2,4}(x)\\
B_{3,4}(x)\\
B_{4,4}(x)\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
such that empty entries in the matrix are filled with zeros. It's not too hard to find the inverse of the change-of-basis matrix above. We obtain
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1\\
&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{2}{4}&\frac{3}{4}&\frac{4}{4}\\
&&\frac{1}{6}&\frac{3}{6}&\frac{6}{6}\\
&&&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{4}{4}\\
&&&&\frac{1}{1}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
B_{0,4}(x)\\
B_{1,4}(x)\\
B_{2,4}(x)\\
B_{3,4}(x)\\
B_{4,4}(x)\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\x\\x^2\\x^3\\x^4
\end{pmatrix}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
Here we have again an upper triangle matrix where empty entries are filled with zeros. We can write the entries in the change-of-basis matrix (2) in a form which can be easily generalized:
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
\binom{0}{0}&\binom{1}{0}&\binom{2}{0}
&\binom{3}{0}&\binom{4}{0}\\
&\frac{1}{4}\binom{1}{1}&\frac{1}{4}\binom{2}{1}
&\frac{1}{4}\binom{3}{1}&\frac{1}{4}\binom{4}{1}\\
&&\frac{1}{6}\binom{2}{2}
&\frac{1}{6}\binom{3}{2}&\frac{1}{6}\binom{4}{2}\\
&&&\frac{1}{4}\binom{3}{3}&\frac{1}{4}\binom{4}{3}\\
&&&&\binom{4}{4}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
B_{0,4}(x)\\
B_{1,4}(x)\\
B_{2,4}(x)\\
B_{3,4}(x)\\
B_{4,4}(x)\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\x\\x^2\\x^3\\x^4
\end{pmatrix}\tag{3}
\end{align*}

> We obtain from (3) for general $n$:
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{j=k}^n\binom{j}{n}\binom{n}{k}^{-1}B_{j,n}(x)=x^k\qquad\qquad 0\leq k\leq n}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

With the transformation (4) we can then represent polynomials $p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k$ in terms of $B_{j,n}, 0\leq j\leq n$.

Comment: So the main idea is to transform the basis functions to their equivalent in the canonical base, do the standard long division and translate back to the old basis. Indeed, the matrix is easy invertible which makes this a good approach

Comment: @CarlosAdir: Yes, this approach is often helpful when considering transformations of this kind.